# Using Ordinal Variables as categories in XGBoost Python

Tags: python, pandas, classification, xgboost, data-preprocessing

I am trying to train a multi-class classifier using XGBoost. Data contains 4 independent variables which are ordinal in nature. I want to use these variables as is because they are encoded. The data looks like below

| Column name | Values |
| --- | --- |
| target | ['high', 'medium', 'low'] |
| feature_1 | Values ranging from 1-5 |
| feature_2 | Values ranging from 1-5 |
| feature_3 | Values ranging from 1-5 |
| feature_4 | Values ranging from 1-5 |

My code currently look like below

```
y = data['target']
X = data.drop(['target'], axis=1)

X = X.fillna(0)
X = X.astype('int').astype('category')

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20, random_state=random_state, stratify=y)

# Create instance of model
xgb_model = XGBClassifier()

# Create the random grid
xgb_grid = {'n_estimators': [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 100, stop = 500, num = 5)],
            'max_depth': [3, 5, 8, 10],
            'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]}

xgb_model_tuned = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = xgb_model, param_distributions = xgb_grid, n_iter = 50, cv = 5, scoring='roc_auc', verbose=2, random_state=random_state, n_jobs = -1)

# Pass training data into model
xgb_model_tuned.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I get the following error when i run this

```
ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or categorical.  When
                categorical type is supplied, DMatrix parameter
                `enable_categorical` must be set to `True`.feature_1, feature_2, 
                feature_3, feature_4
```

The dtype is `category` for all the variables. This worked well with RandomForest Classifier but not with XGBoost. If i cannot use the datatype `category` how can i pass the ordinal variables as categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them treated as ordinal, then just make the column type `int`: xgboost will make splits as though they were continuous, which preserves the ordered nature.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there!

Based on [XGBoost Documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/categorical.html), you need to set `enable_categorical=True` and the supported tree methods are `gpu_hist`, `approx`, and `hist`.

```
# Create instance of model
xgb_model = XGBClassifier(tree_method="gpu_hist", enable_categorical=True)
```

Also, ensure that your XGBoost version is 1.5 and above.